# How to update a row with Uniface 9.7

Tags: informix, uniface

How can I update a row in Informix 12.10 with Uniface 9.7?

Can somebody show me an example?

Here is my example. But it does not work:

```
entry UpdateEntity
returns numeric

    params
        string  ps_entityAsList : IN 
    endparams

    variables
        numeric nRet
        string  s_Entity
    endvariables

    ;--------------------------------------------------
    ; Inits
    ;--------------------------------------------------
    nRet = 0
    s_Entity = "CAR"

    clear/e s_Entity

    ;fill entity "CAR"
    getlistitems/occ/init ps_entityAsList, s_Entity

    ; if some error on filling the entity
    if ( $status < 1 )
        call errorMessage("Error")
        return (-1)
    endif

    ;---------------------------------
    ;update the entity in the database
    ;---------------------------------
    store/e s_Entity

    ;----------------------------
    ; if some error on updating
    ;----------------------------
    if ( $status < 0 )
        call errorMessage("Error")
        return (-1)
    endif

    ; ---------------------------
    ; if no error
    ; ---------------------------
    return (0)

end
```

The store method does not update the entity/row in the table.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading the record from the database, therefore there is nothing to update.
The action sequence is:

- clear
- Fill the key
- retrieve the record
- fill the new values of the record
- store

Comment: Thank you. I had put values from a web service call to an struct object, which have the same properties like the entity i want to update. The struct object i saved into a string and call the string 'ps_entityAsList' with the entry 'UpdateEntity'. The entry should put the values from the string into the entity and update the values which are not the old values from the entity.